# Conditonal expectation $\mathbb{E}(A^2\mid A+B = 2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $A,B$ are independent random variables, wherein $A$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2]$ and $B$ is uniformly distributed on $[1,3]$.

Find $\mathbb{E}(A^2\mid A+B = 2)$

As I understand I need to use Joint Probability Density Function.

Could you give an advise how can I proceed?

Comment: The conditional event doesn't make sense here since $\mathbb{P}(A + B = 2) = 0$

Comment: @Thành Nguyễn: it has solution, but I don"t know how to proceed exactly

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, if I remember correctly, $$ \mathbb{E}(X \vert A) = \dfrac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A)} \mathbb{E}(X \cdot 1_A) $$ So it seems weird to me that $\mathbb{P}(A) = 0$

Comment: @Sine of the Time: yes, it's equal

Comment: You need to find the conditional density of $A$ given $A+B$. For that, use a change of variables to find the joint density of $A$ and $A+B$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: Could you provide more information how to use it, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Discussion about a correct formulation.** (This part can be skipped if the reader is not familiar with the measure-theoretic approach to probability theory.)

As pointed out by other users, it is meaningless to discuss the value of the particular conditional expectation $\mathbf{E}[A^2 \mid A+B = 2]$. On the other hand, it is meaningful the discuss the **function**

$$ x \mapsto \mathbf{E}[A^2 \mid A+B = x] \tag{1} $$

through [*regular conditional probability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability). (If $\mu_X(\cdot) = \mathbf{P}(X \in \cdot)$ denotes the law of $X$, then this function is defined only up to $\mu_X$-almost-everywhere sense.)

Let me discuss how we can compute $\text{(1)}$. Let $\mathbf{P}(\cdot \mid X = x)$ denote a version of regular conditional probability given $X$. Then the standard result tells that, if $(X, Y)$ has a join density $f_{X,Y}$ and $f_X$ is the corresponding marginal density of $X$,

$$ \mathbf{E}[\varphi(X, Y) \mid X = x] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x, y) \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)} \, \mathrm{d}y $$

holds for $\mu_X$-almost every $x$, for any bounded continuous function $\varphi$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

---

**Computing the conditional expectation.** We first identify the joint density $f_{A,X}$ of $A$ and $X = A+B$, as well as the marginal density $f_X$ of $X$.

**1.** To compute $f_{A,X}$, we may invoke the [change of variables formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Vector_to_vector), which immediately yields

$$ f_{A,X}(a, x)
= f_{A}(a)f_B(x-a)
= \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{1}_{[0,2]}(a) \cdot \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{1}_{[1,3]}(x-a) \tag{2} $$

Alternatively, let $\varphi(a, x)$ be any *test function*. Then the integral of $\varphi$ against the joint density $f_{A,X}$ satisfies

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \varphi(a, x) f_{A,X}(a, x) \, \mathrm{d}a\mathrm{d}x
&= \mathbf{E}[\varphi(A, X)]
= \mathbf{E}[\varphi(A, A + B)] \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \varphi(a, a+b) f_{A}(a)f_B(b) \, \mathrm{d}a\mathrm{d}b  \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \varphi(a, x) f_{A}(a)f_B(x-a) \, \mathrm{d}a\mathrm{d}x. \tag{$x=a+b$}
\end{align*}

Comparing both sides and noting that $\varphi$ is arbitrary, we conclude $\text{(2)}$.

**2.** Next, we turn to computing $f_X$. Since $A$ and $B$ are independent, the density of $X$ can be computed by invoking the convolution formula. However, it can also be computed by marginalizing the joint density of $A$ and $X$. In fact, both leads to the same formula:

\begin{align*}
f_X(x)
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_A(a)f_B(x-a) \, \mathrm{d}a \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{1}_{[0,2]}(a) \cdot \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{1}_{[1,3]}(x-a) \, \mathrm{d}a \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4} \mathbf{1}_{[0,2]}(a) \mathbf{1}_{[x-3,x-1]}(a) \, \mathrm{d}a \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \operatorname{length}([0, 2] \cap [x-3, x-1]) \\
&= \begin{cases}
0, & x \leq 1, \\
\frac{x-1}{4}, & 1 \leq x \leq 3, \\
\frac{5-x}{4}, & 3 \leq x \leq 5, \\
0, & x \geq 5
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

**3.** Now we invoke the formula. Note that the law $\mu_X$ of $X$ is supported on $[1, 5]$. Let $x$ satisfy $1 < x < 5$. Then the conditional density of $A$ is computed as

\begin{align*}
\frac{f_{A,X}(a,x)}{f_X(x)}
&= \frac{\frac{1}{4} \mathbf{1}_{[0,2]}(a) \mathbf{1}_{[x-3,x-1]}(a)}{f_X(x)} \\
&= \begin{cases}
\frac{\frac{1}{4} \mathbf{1}_{[0,2]}(a) \mathbf{1}_{[x-3,x-1]}(a)}{\frac{x-1}{4}}
= \frac{\mathbf{1}_{[0,x-1]}(a)}{x-1}
= f_{\mathcal{U}[0,x-1]}(a), & 1 < x \leq 3, \\
\frac{\frac{1}{4} \mathbf{1}_{[0,2]}(a) \mathbf{1}_{[x-3,x-1]}(a)}{\frac{5-x}{4}}
= \frac{\mathbf{1}_{[x-3,2]}(a)}{5-x}
= f_{\mathcal{U}[x-3,2]}(a), & 3 \leq x < 5.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Here, $f_{\mathcal{U}[p, q]}$ denotes the density of $\mathcal{U}[a, b]$, the uniform distribution over the interval $[a, b]$. Consequently,

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[A^2 \mid A+B = x]
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} a^2 \frac{f_{A,X}(a,x)}{f_X(x)} \, \mathrm{d}a \\
&= \begin{cases}
\frac{(x-1)^3 - 0^3}{3(x-1)}
= \frac{(x-1)^2}{3}, & 1 < x \leq 3, \\
\frac{2^3 - (x-3)^3}{3(5-x)}
= \frac{x^2 - 4x + 7}{3}, & 3 \leq x < 5.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much! Excellent solution. Could you recommend me to read something on this kind of ideas?

Comment: Hello, nice solution! May I ask you to elaborate on why it is meaningless to discuss this problem in the initial setting and how it is different from function (1). Your solution is exactly what I would had done, If I saw this kind of problem. And I don't see a problem in initial setting

Comment: @Metso, Thank you! As for your question, I believe you may be able to find them on any standard probability textbook (except for the first part where I briefly mentioned something about measure theory).

Comment: @Claptar, The main issue is that $\{A+B=2\}$ has zero probability of happening. This has two implications: **(1)** The individual value $\mathbf{E}[A^2\mid A+B=2]$ is not well-defined. **(2)** Even when we can make sense of it, this individual value does not contribute when it comes to reconstructing unconditional quantities like $\mathbf{E}[A^2 \mathbf{1}_{\{A+B\in E\}}]$. This can be seen from the formula $$\mathbf{E}[A^2\mathbf{1}_{\{A+B\in E\}}]=\int_{E}\mathbf{E}[A^2\mid A+B=x]f_{A+B}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x,$$ where the integral is not affected by modifying the integrand at finitely many points.

Answer (score 0):

The conditioning term $A+B=2$ is an event. The conditional expectation of a random variable on an event is defined as follows:
$$
\mathbb{E}\big[ A^2 \big] = \int_0^2 x^2 \cdot P(A = x \, \big| \,  A+B=2)\, \text{d}x.
$$
However, the conditional probability of $A=x$ given that given that $A+B+2$ is not well-defined, as we have that $P(A+B=2)$ is zero as Tanh Nguyen pointed out. This is because

\begin{align}
P(A+B=2) 
&= \int_0^2 P(A=x, B = 2-x) \, \text{d}x \\
&= \int_0^2 P(A=x)  P(B = 2-x) \, \text{d}x \\
&= \int_0^2 0 \, \text{d}x \\
&= 0.
\end{align}

So, I am pretty sure that this problem has no solution. But, you seem adamant that there is a solution so maybe I am wrong. I would have commented this, but I am not yet allowed to as my account is still new. Where did you find this exercise?